# Arduino Error: 'val' does not name a type

Tags: arduino, sensors, arduino-uno

Some students from my school are working on a project to measure vibrations (eg. earthquakes) and print the results from two sensors (Piezo knock and vibration sensor) to lcd shield. They probably compiled some codes from the internet. Their original code was like this:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);
int referansDegeri = 800;
int knockSensor = 0;               
int val = 0;
int sensorLevel = map;
int statePin = LOW;
int THRESHOLD = 100;
const int analogPin = A0;
int vib_pin=7;

void setup()
{
  int sensorReading = analogRead(analogPin);
  // map the result to a range from 0 to the number of LEDs:
  int sensorLevel = map(sensorReading, 0, 1023, 0, sensorCount);
  pinMode(vib_pin,INPUT);
Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop()
{
int sensorDegeri = analogRead(A0);
Serial.print(sensorDegeri); //Okuduğumuz değer ekrana yazdırılıyor
if (sensorDegeri >= referansDegeri){
Serial.println("siddetli sarsinti");
}
else{
Serial.println("dusuk sarsinti");
}
delay(1);
}

 val = analogRead(knockSensor);     
  if (val >= THRESHOLD) {
    statePin = !statePin;
    digitalWrite(ledPin, statePin);
    Serial.println("Knock!");
  delay(100);

int val;
  val=digitalRead(vib_pin);
  if(val==1)
  {
    digitalWrite(led_pin,HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(led_pin,LOW);
    delay(1000);
   }
   else
   digitalWrite(led_pin,LOW);
}
```

This code gave this error (exit status):

> 'sensorCount' was not declared in this scope

Knowing that the students have one knock sensor, I changed the sensorCount to 1 while mapping it so it would seem

```
int sensorLevel = map(sensorReading, 0, 1023, 0, 1);
```

then it started giving this error (exit status):

> 'val' does not name a type

I made some search however, could not find a specific result so cannot fix the problem. But I believe it is important to mention that students were using LED Bar Graph previously, alongside LCD shield, but they have now removed it.

Comment: In the C++ every command must be inside of function. The `val = analogRead(knockSensor);` is an command and it's not inside of function. Try to use keystroke `ctrl+T` and the Arduino IDE will reformat (=indent) code for you so you can see, it's not the part of `loop` function.

Comment: Moreover, there are plenty more errors in the code, starting with `int sensorLevel = map;` - what is map? A function assigned to integer? `sensorLevel` is assigned but never used, and the name of last parameter of `map` is `toHigh` (higher bound of new range) which with value of 1 would map read values 0-1022 to 0 and just 1023 = 1 which was probably not intended.